# SIM/USIM authentification with osmo-sim-auth Python script

Tags: python

I would try to reproduce the USIM authentication process using a PC-based SIM card reader using the following Python script (not that I must use this one, but I didn't find another): https://osmocom.org/projects/osmo-sim-auth

My card SIM reader is functional and detected:

```
$ pcsc_scan 
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.5.2 (c) 2001-2017, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: Gemalto Prox Dual USB PC Link Reader [Prox-DU Contactless_13101538] 00 00
1: Gemalto Prox Dual USB PC Link Reader [Prox-DU Contact_13101538] 01 00

Thu Oct 18 08:51:09 2018
Reader 0: Gemalto Prox Dual USB PC Link Reader [Prox-DU Contactless_13101538] 00 00
Card state: Card removed, 
Reader 1: Gemalto Prox Dual USB PC Link Reader [Prox-DU Contact_13101538] 01 00
Card state: Card inserted, 
ATR: 3B 9F 96 80 3F C6 A0 80 31 E0 73 F6 21 16 57 4A 4D 02 0B 34 54 63 69

ATR: 3B 9F 96 80 3F C6 A0 80 31 E0 73 F6 21 16 57 4A 4D 02 0B 34 54 63 69
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
...
```

The pcscd service is running:

```
systemctl status pcscd
● pcscd.service - PC/SC Smart Card Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pcscd.service; indirect; v
Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-10-18 08:57:02 CEST; 1
    Docs: man:pcscd(8)
Main PID: 23039 (pcscd)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/pcscd.service
        └─23039 /usr/sbin/pcscd --foreground --auto-exit
```

However, then I run the `osmo-sim-auth.py` script, I got the following error:

```
./osmo-sim-auth.py -r 00000000000000000000000000000000 -s
Testing SIM card with IMSI None

GSM Authentication
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./osmo-sim-auth.py", line 125, in <module>
    handle_sim(options, rand_bin)
File "./osmo-sim-auth.py", line 75, in handle_sim
    print "SRES:\t%s" % b2a_hex(byteToString(ret[0]))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Information you are trying can not be read without RAND value which is generated in AUC/HLR for GSM. GSM network authenticates SIM using the challenge-response mechanism.

- Once the authentication is required, AUC/HLR provides 128 bit RAND(Random Number), Kc and SRES values to MSC/VLR.
- RAND is sent to the SIM encrypted .
- SIM using A3, A8 algorithms, GSM SIM authentication key (Ki) and RAND value calculates SRES and Kc
- SRES is derived from A3 (RAND, Ki). Kc is derived from A8 (RAND, Ki).
- Ki is Authentication key which assigned by SIM vendor with the versions of A3 and A8.
- SIM sends SRES to MSC/VLR
- If two SRES values match, authentication is done.

You need RAND value for GSM , RAND/AUTN values for UMTS, Ki, A3 and A8 algorithm types.

Answer (score 0):

your command it's for GSM card, if you try UMTS , you must add the -a